# How do I rotate a plot of a system of functions?

Tags: plotting, rotation

I created a plot of a system of functions. I don't need any explicit formals, I just want to export a graphic that shows what it "looks like" if I rotate my plot by exactly a specified angle, but I don't see any rotation handles when I hover over the corners of the plot or anywhere to enter an angle.

Comment: Like, do you want to rotate everything including the axes of the plot? Or are you just trying to rotate the functions themselves?

Comment: Maybe you can just use `Rotate[plot, angle]`?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT 1:**

If you just want to rotate the whole image, that's actually much simpler. Try:

```
plot1 = Plot[x^2, {x, -5, 5}];
Rotate[plot1, -Pi/4]
```

or, more concisely:

```
Rotate[Plot[x^2, {x,-5, 5}], -Pi/4]
```

[image]

**Original:**

I assume you just want to rotate the function itself and keep the axes in the normal position. I'm not sure how to do this with `Plot`, but by defining your functions and created some data, you can do it pretty easily using `ListLinePlot` and `RotationMatrix`. You can try:

```
f[x_] := x^2
data = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, -5, 5, 0.1}];
ListLinePlot[
  {data, data.RotationMatrix[-Pi/4]},
  AspectRatio -> 1
]
```

[image: Rotated function of x squared.]

Comment: But I appreciate your answer but I am actually trying to rotate the whole axis.

Comment: @askmathquestions I've edited my answer.